# Use SuppressStaticInitializationFor from PowerMock in Mockito 3.5.x

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

We try to migrate powermock with mockito 2 to mockito 3.5.x, because PowerMock is to slowly. Its possible to use the functionality @SuppressStaticInitializationFor from PowerMock in Mockito 3.5.x? We cannot change the mocking class, because it's a class from a 3rd Library.